# Functional degradation w/ Firefox 22, FireBug 1.11.4, and FirePath 0.9.7

Tags: firefox, webdriver, firebug

Just yesterday I finally got the right combination of versions for Firefox (22) FireBug (1.11.4) and FirePath (0.9.7) working.  With the aforementioned add-on's enabled the test app does not function properly.  Specifically navigation to different pages in the app results in new instance of the app at the desired page.  I had 5 or 6 instances running before I noticed this on the first occurrence.  Disable the add-on's and all is well.  This is all in the context of Selenium webDriver.  Suggestions?

Comment: Do you see errors in the Firefox console (CTRL+SHIFT+J)? If possible, could you share the link to the test app + give exact steps to reproduce so we can see what happens?

Comment: Bizarre.  Not sure what provoked the problem but it simply disappeared. Will look into diagnostics further if I ever get it to repeat again.

Comment: Great. Let us know if you encounter the same issue on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebug. Thanks!